# How to send offline permission request to facebook users?

Tags: php, facebook

Dear All, 
I have created an facebook application to update the user status.and it is working find..But now i want to send permission request to my knows persons to  allow my application for particular access permission.Using the facebook link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ i can do it easily.But here the particular user need to login.The code is below available on facebook:

> 

```
$app_id = YOUR_APP_ID;
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_URL";
$code = $_REQUEST["code"];
if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);

    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}
$token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&client_secret="
    . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;
$access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" . $access_token;
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
echo("Hello " . $user->name);
```

?>

Now my question is: HOW I SEND TO APPLICATION ACCESS REQUEST ON OFFLINE TO PARTICULAR USER USING USERID?

Let say i have a database of 100 facebook users id. Now i want to send them to allow my application? How i do that?

I shall be very much glud if any body can help me to send the application request to user using user ID.

Thanks in Advance
Riad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question pls see my answer and code on:

> [How get facebook user ID from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780416/how-get-facebook-user-id-from-my-application/5788478#5788478)

Hope it will help u all.
thx,riad

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send it to offline. Connect is only possible for the currently available users that instantiate that process themselves.

Probably you may solve it with [application requests](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/)?